# javascript variable to use insde html onclick

Tags: javascript, html

i have this javascript variable

```
<script>var onclick_url_bid_o_matic = $(this).parent().find('.do_bid').data('urll');</script>
```

and this html button

```
 <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="bido blu" onclick="+onclick_url_bid_o_matic+" id="btn-bidoo">Activate</a>
```

the javascript variable points to this:

```
data-urll="<?php
     if($whim_available >= 1)
   {
       if($details['reward_type']=="play_to_win")
         {

    echo '$.auctions.bid(' .$details['id']  . ', $(this), event);';
         }
        if($details['reward_type']=="whim_it_now")
         {

        echo '$.auctions.claim(' . $details['id']  . ', $(this), event);';
          }

          }
 else
{
    echo "$.auctions.alert('You do not have sufficient Loots');";
      }
    ?>"
```

but the button's onclick doesnt work. and i believe i am not passing the javascript variable right. any help?

Comment: `onclick="+onclick_url_bid_o_matic+"` what are those `+` signs

Comment: i might be wrong with these. i used them to add the variable (or concatinate if u will)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a javascript function:

```
function setVariable(){
    var onclick_url_bid_o_matic = $(this).parent().find('.do_bid').data('urll');
}
```

And call that function in your onClick like so:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="bido blu" onclick="setVariable()" id="btn-bidoo">Activate</a>
```

To test if the variable holds the value needed and that the funtion correctly executed, put it to the console:

```
console.log("Activate link clicked: " + onclick_url_bid_o_matic);
```